# Why does FTP support Anonymous login?

Tags: ftp

I was wondering why FTP supports anonymous login ? Is it not a security issue that anyone can access files on a ftp server without having a real account ? And if anonymous account is a real good thing, what is its importance ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, you'll be better off asking over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If the publisher decided that the resource is public, anonymous access is perfectly valid. Take into account that FTP is just another network protocol as HTTP. If you are not scared about pubic http resources not sure why you should have any concern about FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Historically FTP was widely used for placing files for public access, thus it had to support anonymous login. Note, that most servers don't support "no login" but require something like "Anonymous/guest" or "Anonymous/empty_password" login.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 1635](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1635) describes "anonymous ftp" as follows:

> Anonymous FTP is **a means by which archive sites allow general access
> to their archives of information**.  These sites create a special
> account called "anonymous".  User "anonymous" has **limited access**
> rights to the archive host, as well as **some operating restrictions**.
> In fact, the only operations allowed are logging in using FTP,
> listing the contents of a limited set of directories, and retrieving
> files.  Some sites limit the contents of a directory listing an
> anonymous user can see as well.  Note that "anonymous" users are not
> usually allowed to transfer files TO the archive site, but can only
> retrieve files from such a site.

So, it's just a way to give **the general public** access to your server. To do this, you need to provide a **username that everybody knows** (i.e. 'anonymous') without a specific password (i.e. any e-mail address will do). But since everybody can access, you want to protect your content against changes, by enforcing **heavy operating restrictions**.